# Microsoft Azure Linux VM domain redirection

Tags: linux, azure

I've a Azure Linux VM created with the domain ***something.cloudapp.net*** which I'm using to host a REST API for a app. Now for some reason I've to host the API on some other server, which will change the endpoint to which the app is sending requests.

My question is, can we redirect any request to ***something.cloudapp.net*** to my new domain. So that I don't need to update the url in the app. Because if I change it in the app, a new update has to be released and the users who don't update the app will not be able to use it.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've hardcoded the **.cloudapp.net** URL in the app and not your own domain (with a CNAME to **.cloudapp.net**), then you still need to keep a service running at the original URL that will send a `HTTP 301` redirect (Moved Permanently)** back to the clients.

Hopefully your client application understands and follows HTTP redirects. Test that first!

There is no way to CNAME the **.cloudapp.net** domain to point to something arbitrary since that domain is owned by Microsoft. Only the other way around is possible.

Sample redirect with `web.config`
(source: https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect):

```xml
<system.webServer>
   <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://your.new.url/" />
</system.webServer>
```

Which results in:

```sh
$ curl -Li http://{something}.cloudapp.net/api/hey_jim_did_we_push_that_fix_to_prod

HTTP/1.1 302 Redirect
Content-Length: 154
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://your.new.url/api/hey_jim_did_we_push_that_fix_to_prod

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 02 Jan 2017 20:06:16 GMT

False
```